# TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined (Angular getters)

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Getting an error in the ts when running test specs. Angular get function().
I have tried creating a spy on the property as such with no success ..

**Spec:**

```
const spyC = spyOnProperty(component, 'contractId').and.returnValue(new 
    FormGroup({}));
```

or

```
const spyC = spyOnProperty(component, 'contractId').and.callThrough();
    expect(spyC).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

**TS:**

```
get contractId() {
        return this.formService.queryParamSnapshot.get('contractId');
      }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems to have to deal with the providers:

```
{provide: AuthService, useClass: MockAuthService}

const fakeActivatedRoute = {
    snapshot: {data: {}}
  } as ActivatedRoute;
```